ArcGIS Dashboard usage statistics
I have an ArcGIS Enterprise account with a custom role and only some administrative privileges. I’m creating a dashboard that needs to show usage statistics on other dashboards throughout our organization – how many total visits and from what parts of the country/world, how many unique visits, date of visit, etc. I was told by my admin that these don’t exist in Portal, only total visits. Is there a way to find these statistics and display them in a dashboard in ArcGIS Online?
